# exporting .png files from a library to a React JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm creating a utility project that will supply React components and resources to my other projects.

I'd like it to include a set of images (mostly .png files for icons) that can then be imported by the child projects.

I can't figure out how to make this work.

I can export the images from the library, and I can see them, name-mangled, in the `node_modules` of the child project. So, all good so far.

But, `import {imgName} from "myLib"` does not include the file in the child project's bundle.

It looks to me like my problem is explained by a clue in https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/:

```
You can import a file right in a JavaScript module. This tells
webpack to include that file in the bundle.
```

Presumably, CRA is not triggering this webpack behavior in my case, since I'm importing from another module,  not from a file.

How can I get things working?

Assume:

- I have complete ownership of the library and child projects, so I can change this solution in whatever way works. I just want to have a single common resource for the images.
- I don't want to eject my child projects
- Ideally, any complexity should be in the library project. The child projects should have minimal complex tooling. (My intent is for this library to be used by a team of other developers, who will want to focus on their own tasks; not on tooling details)

EDIT (ADDED LATER)

Per the comments in the first answer below, I've created a simple example of my problem.  See:

- Library repo: github.com/deg/media-file-bug-library
- Library package: npmjs.com/package/media-file-bug-library
- Client repo: github.com/deg/media-file-bug-client

Just pull the client repo and do `yarn install` and `yarn start`. This will bring up a little web page that shows the problem:

SCREEN SNAPSHOT:

[image: Screen snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is Not in CRA Trigger. Importing Png File like JavaScript Hides a Magic. Here you are importing a Image and Exporting it which then get Processed by bundler and The Bundled Index Actually Exports The name of the Processed Image File  Which in Your Case is `corss~nAalnlvj.png`. That's Why Your Image is Broken but you are able to render name of File, The Case is Same for `microbundle` or `parcel`.

How You Can solve it is by separating your assets and components By Placing Images on separate assets folder and place your images there and then add assets to files in your files in `package.json`

```json
{
  .
  .
  "files": [ "dist", "assets"],
}
```

And Then Import Image & Using Like This

```js
import React from 'react'
import ico_cross from 'media-file-bug-library-fix/assets/cross.png'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src={ico_cross} alt="im"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For Further Reference Checkout
[Here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7353#issuecomment-478282127)

A Npm Library For Your Fix I Published [Npm media-file-bug-library-fix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/media-file-bug-library-fix)

Comment: Thanks!
For further clarity, can you put up a link to your library git repo too?

Comment: this is the Repo (https://github.com/al-chaudhari/media-file-bug-library-fix)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntdUJ.jpg)

hey David I found the solution please do check the above screenshot
as in you package just change in index.modern.js

// WebPack doesnt listen as a path it listen

// var cross = "cross~nAalnlvj.png";

// use import rather than simple name as it generate a full absolute path at parent level so that in child level it can be accessible as an Image

import cross from "./cross~nAalnlvj.png"

Comment: I don't think this works at scale, since it requires knowing the mangled name of the image file, which will change with each build of the library.

Comment: so it is like dynamic name?